# Who is Father Bertet (correspondent of John Collins)?

Tags: mathematicians

[John Collins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Collins_(mathematician)) corresponded with numerous mathematicians in Europe in the 17th century. One of his correspondents mentioned in several letters is one Father Bertet.  Judging from the letters Bertet was in Italy or perhaps more specifically in Venice.  Beyond this I can't find any information on the fellow.  Who was he?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Googling, I found ---

Philip Beeley and Christoph J. Scriba (editors), [**The Correspondence of John Wallis (1616-1703)**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198569483), Volume IV (1672-April 1675), Oxford University Press, 2014.

The following is from p. 506:

> Bertet, Jean (1622-92).--- Born in Tarascon. Admitted S.J. 1637. Studied under Honoré Fabri at Collège de la Trinité in Lyon. Taught philosophy and mathematics at University of Grenoble. By 1659 professor of mathematics at Aix. In 1689 conspired with Leibniz and Antonio Baldigiani S.J. in Rome to have ban on Copernicanism lifted. Died in Paris on 29 June 1692 (new style).

I wonder if Jean is the father or a grandfather of Laurent Dominique Bertet (1671-1739), who seems to be better known?

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. Do Beeley and Scriba say that this Jean Bertet was a correspondent of Collins' ? How can I be sure we got the right guy?

Comment: @Mikhail Katz: I saw enough of the goolge-books preview to know it's the correct person. "Jean Bertet" (on p. 690) is the only "Bertet" in the *Index of Persons and Subjects*, and on p. 529 there is an English translation of a letter from Bertet to Collins (dated 1671/I/26).

Comment: Thanks. My only doubt is that I found a Jean de Bertet who is a different person: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_de_Bertet

Comment: I suggest trying some google-books searches using "Jean" "Bertet" (as separate words, but use quotes) along with one or both of "1678" and "1692". I got [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZFlHAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA275), for example, which discusses the 1622-1692 guy. The things I'm getting are all in French, and I'm not really able to read it well enough to spot things like "not to be confused with Jean Bertet who lived ..." that might show up (and if so, would be exactly what you're looking for). You could also send an email to Beeley and Scriba asking about this other Jean Bertet, I suppose.